# Enabling Nhibernate filters by default

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Is there a way to make sure a filter (`<filter-def>`) in enabled by default as opposed to having to call `session.EnableFilter("filter_name")` everytime?

Answer (score 4):

I understand this may not exactly solve your issue, but this may be done if you wire your objects via an IOC container or if you have a single point where you create the session.

How I've handled it is on activation of ISession I've toggled the filter by default (using Autofac):

```
        builder.RegisterAdapter<ISessionFactory, ISession>(factory => factory.OpenSession())
            .InstancePerHttpRequest()
            .OnActivated(activatedArgs =>
                         {
                             var session = activatedArgs.Instance;
                             session.EnableFilter(MyCustomFilter.Name);
                             session.BeginTransaction();
                         });
```